# "as" keyword in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

In the answers for the tutorials for OCaml available at [this site](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html), some of the solutions, including the one for eliminating consecutive duplicates of list elements, is written as such:

```
let rec compress = function
    | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
    | smaller -> smaller;;
```

What is the relevance of the line `a :: (b:: _ as t)`? Why can't I write it as `a :: b :: t` instead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `t` in `b :: _ as t` is bound to `b :: _`. So the meaning is different. If you use the pattern `a :: b :: t` you would need to say `compress (b :: t)`, which is a little less elegant and a tiny bit less efficient.

Comment: Could you explain why it is less efficient?

Comment: The form with `as` uses the existing tail of the list. The form without `as` conses up a new list from `b` and `t`. So the latter takes a tiny bit of extra time and consumes a small amount of extra space.

Answer (score 13):

**The keyword `as` binds a name to all or part of a pattern.** Once bound, the name can be used instead of the pattern it represents. In your "compress" function, `t` is bound to the pattern `b :: _`. 
Once `t` is bound, it can be used in subsequent expressions, as in the rest of the "compress" function.

`as` name binding occurs left-to-right, unlike most languages (excepting C's typedef). Also, `::` appears to have higher precedence than `as`.

Therefore, `(b :: _ as t)` is equivalent to `((b :: _) as t)`. This can be confusing for those used to right-to-left bindings. Note that `a :: (b :: _) as t` will bind the whole pattern `a :: b :: _` to `t`, due to the precedence mentioned above.

Reference:

- http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html#hevea_manual.kwd7
- http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html.

Comment: Excellent answer