# Keyword "as" in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj

I recently see people using `as` in their SML/NJ program. The most helpful reference I found is ["as" keyword in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769403/as-keyword-in-ocaml).

Though OCaml also belongs to ML programming language family, they are different. For example, in the example program given in the previous answer,

```
let rec compress = function
    | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
    | smaller -> smaller;;
```

My translation of it to SML/NJ is (Please correct me if I have done it wrong)

```
fun compress (a :: (t as b :: _)) = if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
  | compress smaller = smaller
```

As you have seen, the pattern `(b :: _ as t)` has an order different from `(t as b :: _)` in the second snippet. (Still, their usage is pretty much the same)

For potential answers, I hope it can contain (1) reference to this keyword `as` in any among the official documentation of SML/NJ, courses, and books and "maybe" (2) some examples to illustrate its usage. I am hoping this question can help future users seeing `as`.

Comment: @JohnColeman `as` is part of '97 revision of SML. Search for "layered" here: https://people.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml.html Or page 79 in the PDF version of the definition.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan You are correct. For some reason it didn't appear in a list of SML keywords that I consulted, but I was able to find it in documentation for successor SML so I assumed it was one of the extensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `as` keyword is part of the Standard ML definition ('97 revision). See [page 79, figure 22](http://sml-family.org/sml97-defn.pdf#page=93) (highlighting mine):

[image]

These are called as-patterns in Haskell and pretty much any other language that allows binding an identifier to a (sub-)pattern, but the origin of the name is clearly from ML.

The purpose it serves is to give a name to a pattern or a part of it. For example, we can capture the whole head of a 2-tuple list, while at the same assigning names to the tuple's values.

```
fun example1 (list : (int * string) list) =
  case list of
    (* `head` will be bound to the tuple value *)
    (* `i` will be bound to the tuple's 1st element *)
    (* `s` will be bound to the tuple's 2nd element *)
    head as (i, s) :: tail => ()
  | nil => ()
```

The other usage appears in record patterns. Notice that at first sight it might give the impression that the as-name is now to the right of the `as` keyword, but it's not (see the combined example below):

```
fun example2 (list : { foo: int * string } list) =
  case list of
    (* `f` will be found to the value of the `foo` field in the record. *)
    { foo as f } :: tail => ()

    (* The above can also be expressed as follows *)
  | { foo = f } :: tail => ()

  | nil => ()
```

And a combined example, where you can see that `as` usage in records is consistent with its usage elsewhere, i.e., the name stays on the left-hand side of the `as` keyword (here the name is the record label).

```
fun example3 (list : { foo: int * string } list) =
  case list of
    head as { foo as (i, s) } :: tail => ()

    (* This is valid, too, but `foo` is not a binding. *)
  | head as { foo = (i, s) } :: tail => ()

    (* Here, `f` is bound to the whole tuple value. *)
  | head as { foo = f as (i, s) } :: tail => ()

  | nil => ()
```