# Name binding in pattern matching in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, binding, pattern-matching, ocaml

What does the name binding with the as- keyword do in this exercise:
https://ocaml.org/problems#17

```
# let split list n =
    let rec aux i acc = function
      | [] -> List.rev acc, []
      | h :: t as l -> if i = 0 then List.rev acc, l
                       else aux (i - 1) (h :: acc) t 
    in
      aux n [] list;;
```

Does it allow us to choose in the if / else clause whether the tail `t` or the list `l` is used in the function pattern matching?
What is the common use of name binding in functional Programming?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["as" keyword in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769403/as-keyword-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as` keyword allows you to bind a name to larger and smaller parts of a pattern.  In the example you provided:

> ```
> let split list n =
>   let rec aux i acc = function
>   | [] -> List.rev acc, []
>   | h::t as l -> if i = 0 then List.rev acc, l
>                  else aux (i - 1) (h :: acc) t 
>   in
>   aux n [] list
> ```

`l` is bound to the entire list, and `h` is bound to the head of the list and `t` to the tail.

Without `as` you might write:

```
let split list n =
  let rec aux i acc = function
  | [] -> List.rev acc, []
  | h::t -> if i = 0 then List.rev acc, (h::t)
            else aux (i - 1) (h :: acc) t 
  in
  aux n [] list
```

Keep in mind that `as` is "greedy" to its left, and parentheses may be needed to disambiguate precedence.

E.g.

```
h::h'::t as lst
```

The entire list is bound to `lst`.

If you want to to bind the tail, but also the second element in a list:

```
h::(h'::_ as tl)
```